# Error parsing JSON which starts with "var ..."

Tags: javascript, json

I got into a little thing while getting a **JSON** file from a server, the ***JSON file*** contains something like this:

```
var reviews = [
    {
        "firstName":"Simon", 
        "lastName":"Lock",
        "fullName":"Simon Lock",
        "location":"San Francisco",
        "reviewTitle":"Super quality.. I will show here again!",
        "reviewBody":"Super nice quality, fast devilery, good prices. I will shop here again!",
        "starRating":"5"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"John", 
        "lastName":"Smith",
        "fullName":"John Smith",
        "location":"New York",
        "reviewTitle":"Princely Sum",
        "reviewBody":"A decent local curry house in Faversham, Kent known for its Elvis nights.",
        "starRating":"4"        
    },
];
```

And as expected, I get an error while getting the file with `$.ajax`:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token v
```

Since is not a valid JSON format, but I did also try to do it with another kind of `dataType`.
My question is:

Is there any way to get that variable in JSON file stored in another variable so it can be manipulated normally?

also I did try to use `FileReader()` but I didn't work for me.

thanks

Comment: It's not really JSON at all, it's a javascript object.

Comment: you have an extra comma at the end of second object.

Comment: I can't access the json file at the moment, so is there any way to do it? otherwise I will just re do the API when i have the server credentials

Comment: You can fetch it with a `script`, but you need to realize that this is a JavaScript program, not a "json file". `var s = document.createElement("script"); s.src = "/your/path/to/data"; document.body.appendChild(s);` Then after the script is done loading, your variable will be available as `window.reviews`. No need to parse it, since it was eval'd as a JavaScript program.

Comment: ...and you'll need to wait until the script is loaded to access it. The `onload` of a script doesn't work in older IE, so you may need to do some polling for `window.reviews`.

Comment: @cookiemonster thanks mate(?!), this actually made it, I just need it to see it as a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is just a way of storing data, not JavaScript code. it doesn't know what to do with `var reviews =`.  All you store in your JSON file is the data, like below.

```
[
    {
        "firstName":"Simon", 
        "lastName":"Lock",
        "fullName":"Simon Lock",
        "location":"San Francisco",
        "reviewTitle":"Super quality.. I will show here again!",
        "reviewBody":"Super nice quality, fast devilery, good prices. I will shop here again!",
        "starRating":"5"
    }, 
    {
        "firstName":"John", 
        "lastName":"Smith",
        "fullName":"John Smith",
        "location":"New York",
        "reviewTitle":"Princely Sum",
        "reviewBody":"A decent local curry house in Faversham, Kent known for its Elvis nights.",
        "starRating":"4"        
    }
]
```

Comment: So there is no way to avoid re doing that, well to make a proper API for this people, thanks mate :)

Comment: The last trailing comma also need to be removed, since JSON unfortunately doesn't allow those.

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that this is not something I recommend in cases where security is critical, but you do have the option of using the `eval()` function on the plain text of the file.

```
eval('var reviews = [
  {
    "firstName":"Simon", 
    "lastName":"Lock",
    "fullName":"Simon Lock",
    "location":"San Francisco", ...
```

would give you a variable reviews that contains the object you want.

edit: ***yes*** eval is evil, I know

Comment: +1 Valid solution, though I'd prefer to just load it as a script if possible. Also, using The `Function` constructor avoids the  serious performance penalty often found in modern browsers when using `eval()`... Like this: `var f = new Function(my_data); f();` or in one statement: `new Function(my_data)();` It also uses the global scope instead of the local. Other than that, it's basically the same.

Comment: In this situation, I believe a substr would be preferred over an eval(). Yes, they are evil.